# Decompose np.einsum into np.dot operations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum, tensor

I want to do a summation over a 4-D tensor and corresponding coefficients. One could use 4 nested `for` loops to get the right answer.

But we all know that `for` loops are two slow in Python. Here I instead use np.einsum to get a result, like:

```py
import numpy as np

D = np.arange(4).reshape(2, 2)
i, j, k, l = 1, 0, 1, 1 # index < 2

tensor_S = np.arange(16).reshape(2, 2, 2, 2)
SUM_ijkl = np.einsum('a, b, c, d, abcd', D[i], D[j], D[k], D[l], tensor_S)
```

This looks quite concise, but I learnt `np.einsum` is implemented in pure Python, see it [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/22604), so it might be an efficiency issue when encountering large tensors. I want to know how to decompose this kind of summation to dot product or matrix multiplication to guarantee the computation efficiency, or get the result via other alternative fast functions.

I have limited experience dealing with tensors, so any comment helps!

Thanks!

Comment: How far down the linked thread did you go? https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/22604#issuecomment-1344328463

Comment: Postulate is false. Btw, pure python is wayyyyy slower than that. For heavy computation (on whole big set of data), we are talking factor 1000 between a pure python implementation and something that relies on C. So, rule of thumb, is someone explains a difference from 21ms to 363ms by  a heavy C code written in pure python, that person doesn't know what they are talking about. And then comparing mono-thread code with potentially multi CPU/GPU implementations... yes, things run faster when you spread on CPU and GPU, but this has nothing to do with pure python.

Answer (score 1):

First, in `numpy` 'tensors' aren't something special.  It flexibly handles 1d, 2d, and nd arrays in the same way.

`einsum` has a layer of code (whether python or c) that analizes the calculation, taking into account the indexing and the size of the arguments, and from that breaks it into one or more calculations.  Where possible it will use the same BLAS library functions that `np.dot` and `np.matmul` use.

You can explore its action with the `optimize` parameter, and the `einsum_path` function (see the documenation)

For example, with the default optimize (`True`) it 'decomposes' your calculation as:

```
In [166]: print(np.einsum_path('a, b, c, d, abcd', D[i], D[j], D[k], D[l], tensor_S)[1])
  Complete contraction:  a,b,c,d,abcd->
         Naive scaling:  4
     Optimized scaling:  4
      Naive FLOP count:  8.000e+01
  Optimized FLOP count:  6.100e+01
   Theoretical speedup:  1.311
  Largest intermediate:  8.000e+00 elements
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
scaling                  current                                remaining
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   4                 abcd,a->bcd                              b,c,d,bcd->
   3                   bcd,b->cd                                 c,d,cd->
   2                     cd,c->d                                    d,d->
   1                       d,d->                                       ->
```

`d,d->` is a simple `dot` to 2 1d array, yielding a scalar.  `cd,c->d` is a 2d with 1d, yielding a 1d.  `abcd,a->bcd` could be done by reshaping the first argument into a 2d (a,b*c*d) shape, and then back to (b,c,d).  `np.tensordot` does that kind of reshaping to reduce its calculations to a simple `dot`.

Turing off `optimize`, `einsum` uses its own compiled code to do the contraction in one step.  Years ago I replicated this sort of calculation with `cython` and `nditer` to effectively iterate over the whole `a,b,c,d` space.

```
In [167]: print(np.einsum_path('a, b, c, d, abcd', D[i], D[j], D[k], D[l], tensor_S,optimize=False)[1])
  Complete contraction:  a,b,c,d,abcd->
         Naive scaling:  4
     Optimized scaling:  4
      Naive FLOP count:  8.000e+01
  Optimized FLOP count:  8.100e+01
   Theoretical speedup:  0.988
  Largest intermediate:  1.000e+00 elements
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
scaling                  current                                remaining
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   4              abcd,d,c,b,a->
```

Which 'optimize' choice gives best performance can vary - with the indexing, but also with the size of the arrays.  What's good for your small example, might not be best from large arrays.

Often when SO ask about some complex matrix multiplication case, I find it's easiest to express with `einsum`.  But then I try to rework it as a `matmul/@` (or in your case several).  That can require some transpose and/or reshapes.  The `matmul` version can be faster, but never by orders of magnitude.

Your `einsum` could be written as a sequence of `dot`,

```
In [170]: SUM_ijkl
Out[170]: 1325

In [171]: np.dot(D[l], np.dot(D[k], np.dot(D[j], np.dot(D[i], tensor_S.reshape(2,-1)).reshape(2,-1)).reshape(2,-1)).reshape(2,-1))
Out[171]: array([1325])
```

Since all dimensions are the same, it doesn't match which order we take them.  If they differed, `einsum_path` might chose a different order, most likely condensing the largest first to reduce problem space faster.

Some comparative times

```
In [172]: timeit np.dot(D[l], np.dot(D[k], np.dot(D[j], np.dot(D[i], tensor_S.reshape(2,-1)).reshape(2,-1)).reshape(2,-1)).reshape(2,-1))
22.7 µs ± 100 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [173]: timeit np.einsum('a, b, c, d, abcd', D[i], D[j], D[k], D[l], tensor_S)
18.3 µs ± 49.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [174]: timeit np.einsum('a, b, c, d, abcd', D[i], D[j], D[k], D[l], tensor_S, optimize=False)
19.2 µs ± 22.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [176]: timeit (D[l] @ (D[k] @ (D[j] @ (D[i] @ tensor_S.reshape(2,-1)).reshape(2,-1)).reshape(2,-1)).reshape(2,-1))
22 µs ± 73.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

The last is the same as the `np.dot`, but using the `matmul/@` operator.  Same reshaping